# C# Winform Excel Reading through a query

Tags: c#, excel, winforms

this is my first time to ask question. So please be gentle on me :)

My problem is, I want to format an excel file generated by our time and attendance terminal. Here is the generated excel file and some description of my problem:

[image]

What I want to do is read that excel file using C# Winform and format it as the way way I need it.

**My Problems are:**

- How can I select the sheet? I know that it is only one sheet but I don't know on how to point a sheet using OleDbConnection. Sample in OleDBConnection is "[Sheet1$]" to read a Sheet but I'm not sure on what sheet name will be generated from the terminal. Can we use index? For Example : "from [Sheet1&]" will be "from [0$]"?
- Same as the first problem but in the excel column. How can I treat it as for example, "[0], [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2h0tv.png)".
- Last problem, and will probably explain it all. what I really want to do is use OleDbConnection and my command will be look like this :

  **"SELECT DISTINCT [0$], Convert([1$], Date), MIN(Convert([1$], Time)), MAX(Convert([1$], Time)) FROM [0$] GROUP BY [0$], Convert([1$], Date)"**

Note : [0$] and [1$], are the index of either the columns or the sheets

What I need need is to generate a file that will show the employees attendance that will format with date and there first Time IN for the Day and there last Time Out. Please Look the image below for the idea of the output.

[image]

I've try to search but I'm not able to find a solution that will fits on what I need.

Hope that anyone can help me.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

**For question:**

- Q1: See code note, i have not way to fix this question, if anybody got please sharing to me.
- Q2: Same as first, i have not way to using index by `DateTableName(or Sheet Name)` or `Columns` in SQL.
- Q3: Using Linq. More about Linq samples https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/101-LINQ-Samples-3fb9811b

**These steps are how to get the expected data:**

1. Read all data from Excel file need to know `Sheet Name`;
2. Filter invalid data, because there are many columns value is `empty`, `null` or `space-string` but added to rows;
3. Query data using `Linq`.

Hope that my answer can help you.

**Reference code：**

```
    public void Test()
    {
        string filePath = $"{Environment.CurrentDirectory}//test20170206.xls";
        string conStr = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + filePath + ";Extended Properties='Excel 8.0;HDR=NO;IMEX=1;'";
        //connection excel
        OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(conStr);
        conn.Open();
        //get all sheel from excel file
        DataTable tb = conn.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, null);
        foreach (DataRow row in tb.Rows)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(row["TABLE_NAME"]);
            //using index in row
            for (int i=0;i p.Datetime).ToLongTimeString(), TimeMax = g.Max(p => p.Datetime).ToLongTimeString() };


    }

    public class Model20170206
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public DateTime Datetime { get; set; }
        public string Value1 { get; set; }
        public string Value2 { get; set; }
        public string Value3 { get; set; }
        public string Value4 { get; set; }
    }
```

**Practice steps:**

- I using some test data like this:

```
1,2017-01-28 03:47:54,1,1,1,0
2,2017-01-29 04:58:18,1,0,2,0
3,2017-01-28 08:44:43,1,1,3,0
4,2017-01-28 05:47:56,1,0,4,0
0,2017-02-05 12:12:53,1,1,5,0
1,2017-01-31 12:02:24,1,0,6,0
2,2017-02-05 12:30:34,1,1,7,0
3,2017-02-04 02:30:08,1,0,8,0
4,2017-02-01 11:39:53,1,1,9,0
0,2017-02-05 07:45:58,1,0,10,0
1,2017-02-05 03:01:46,1,1,11,0
2,2017-02-02 09:22:17,1,0,12,0
3,2017-01-30 03:05:46,1,1,13,0
4,2017-02-04 09:02:21,1,0,14,0
0,2017-02-03 07:58:20,1,1,0,0
1,2017-01-29 07:53:48,1,0,1,0
2,2017-01-29 12:41:25,1,1,2,0
3,2017-02-06 02:58:50,1,0,3,0
4,2017-01-28 11:06:47,1,1,4,0
0,2017-02-04 10:40:18,1,0,5,0
1,2017-01-31 12:57:24,1,1,6,0
2,2017-02-03 12:28:38,1,0,7,0
3,2017-02-01 06:48:23,1,1,8,0
4,2017-01-28 12:42:59,1,0,9,0
0,2017-02-04 10:34:44,1,1,10,0
1,2017-02-06 06:38:31,1,0,11,0
2,2017-02-05 08:40:26,1,1,12,0
3,2017-01-31 01:56:32,1,0,13,0
4,2017-02-05 11:13:11,1,1,14,0
0,2017-01-29 10:34:58,1,0,0,0
1,2017-02-02 04:01:18,1,1,1,0
2,2017-02-06 01:08:09,1,0,2,0
3,2017-01-28 07:24:11,1,1,3,0
4,2017-02-02 08:25:50,1,0,4,0
0,2017-01-28 08:01:13,1,1,5,0
1,2017-02-03 08:33:10,1,0,6,0
2,2017-01-29 03:47:03,1,1,7,0
3,2017-02-05 12:36:56,1,0,8,0
4,2017-02-04 06:10:55,1,1,9,0
0,2017-01-29 05:13:43,1,0,10,0
1,2017-02-06 06:35:18,1,1,11,0
2,2017-01-31 08:23:25,1,0,12,0
3,2017-02-03 04:25:10,1,1,13,0
4,2017-01-31 04:31:34,1,0,14,0
0,2017-01-30 10:03:42,1,1,0,0
1,2017-01-30 11:07:57,1,0,1,0
2,2017-02-05 11:17:45,1,1,2,0
3,2017-02-02 12:59:56,1,0,3,0
4,2017-01-31 04:49:48,1,1,4,0
0,2017-02-02 01:02:05,1,0,5,0
1,2017-01-31 11:16:52,1,1,6,0
2,2017-02-03 09:53:51,1,0,7,0
3,2017-01-31 04:02:09,1,1,8,0
4,2017-01-28 05:06:38,1,0,9,0
0,2017-01-28 09:18:28,1,1,10,0
1,2017-02-01 04:26:56,1,0,11,0
2,2017-02-03 11:17:34,1,1,12,0
3,2017-02-06 09:09:23,1,0,13,0
4,2017-01-30 08:20:51,1,1,14,0
0,2017-02-05 06:42:01,1,0,0,0
1,2017-02-01 04:29:38,1,1,1,0
2,2017-02-02 05:28:21,1,0,2,0
3,2017-02-05 04:24:37,1,1,3,0
4,2017-01-31 07:59:14,1,0,4,0
0,2017-01-31 10:38:59,1,1,5,0
1,2017-02-06 03:01:17,1,0,6,0
2,2017-02-02 08:52:25,1,1,7,0
3,2017-02-02 07:47:35,1,0,8,0
4,2017-02-04 07:55:27,1,1,9,0
0,2017-02-06 12:32:50,1,0,10,0
1,2017-01-28 11:01:04,1,1,11,0
2,2017-01-30 01:12:09,1,0,12,0
3,2017-01-29 03:42:15,1,1,13,0
4,2017-02-05 07:00:44,1,0,14,0
0,2017-02-05 05:12:40,1,1,0,0
1,2017-01-28 11:28:18,1,0,1,0
2,2017-02-05 09:11:08,1,1,2,0
3,2017-01-29 09:11:08,1,0,3,0
4,2017-02-04 03:46:57,1,1,4,0
0,2017-02-02 06:21:06,1,0,5,0
1,2017-01-28 02:15:06,1,1,6,0
2,2017-01-31 02:34:50,1,0,7,0
3,2017-02-05 10:14:23,1,1,8,0
4,2017-01-31 05:05:26,1,0,9,0
0,2017-02-05 12:25:46,1,1,10,0
1,2017-02-05 07:15:07,1,0,11,0
2,2017-02-03 04:00:19,1,1,12,0
3,2017-02-06 03:25:13,1,0,13,0
4,2017-02-02 06:01:42,1,1,14,0
0,2017-02-03 04:41:57,1,0,0,0
1,2017-02-06 10:23:15,1,1,1,0
2,2017-01-29 07:45:19,1,0,2,0
3,2017-02-03 11:10:25,1,1,3,0
4,2017-02-05 12:36:33,1,0,4,0
0,2017-02-03 01:51:44,1,1,5,0
1,2017-02-01 08:01:16,1,0,6,0
2,2017-02-01 05:06:28,1,1,7,0
3,2017-01-31 03:20:15,1,0,8,0
4,2017-02-05 07:00:14,1,1,9,0
0,2017-01-31 08:10:04,1,0,10,0
1,2017-02-03 03:23:12,1,1,11,0
2,2017-01-31 10:24:29,1,0,12,0
3,2017-02-04 06:12:08,1,1,13,0
4,2017-01-31 05:24:38,1,0,14,0
0,2017-02-01 08:55:20,1,1,0,0
1,2017-01-29 04:59:03,1,0,1,0
2,2017-02-02 01:05:55,1,1,2,0
3,2017-02-01 10:09:05,1,0,3,0
4,2017-01-30 01:01:37,1,1,4,0
0,2017-02-06 10:57:49,1,0,5,0
1,2017-02-01 08:23:28,1,1,6,0
2,2017-02-01 09:00:45,1,0,7,0
3,2017-01-30 12:16:46,1,1,8,0
0,2017-02-04 06:06:36,1,0,10,0
1,2017-02-01 09:31:02,1,1,11,0
...
more
...
```

- Import them into Excel File look like this :

[image]

- My code result data like this :
  [image]